# Why my bluetooth is choppy and how to test what's wrong?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

My bluetooth speakers and headphones are often choppy.

Currently I seriously think my bluetooth USB dongle, cliptec, sucks. I wonder if buying a better one would solve the problem.

My smartphone can connect to the speakers and headphones just fine. So problem can't be on the speaker.

The problem can be on the dongle or on the usb ports that connect the dongle to the speakers. I wonder how to test that.

My cellphone can connect to my devices just fine without any problems. My PC need some "hacking"

Comment: Because your phone isn't running the same services

Comment: but what are those services? Why do they make sound choppy?

Comment: https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/A2DP.aspx It's to support that Bluetooth feature

Comment: I turned it back on. Actually how do I use that a2dp profile?

Comment: Your devices have to support it.